# why mod_rewrite doesn't work on https pages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When the page hadn't https protocole, this lines of `.htacces` code was working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/productos$
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ /admin/frontend/web/index.php/static/compartir?categorySlug=$1&productSlug=$2 [P]
```

But now, the page have https protocole, so I put `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` to avoid a 500 internal server error, but the redirection doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/productos$
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ /admin/frontend/web/index.php/static/compartir?categorySlug=$1&productSlug=$2 [P]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` specifically instructs mod_rewrite to **not** run if https is on. Instead of preventing that - You should check why You're getting 500 error (See error.log)

Comment: it didn't give nothing in error log. :/ exactly that line works without https